# Is there a more compact way of combining multiple async calls

Tags: swift, async-await

I'm new to async/await in swift and am currently facing a two-part issue.
My goal is to be able to fetch a bunch of Posts like this:

```
func fetchPosts(ids: [Int]) async throws -> [Post] {
  return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Post.self) { taskGroup in
    var posts =  [Post]()
    for id in ids {
      taskGroup.addTask { return try await self.fetchPost(id: id) }
    }
    for try await post in taskGroup {
      posts.append(post)
    }
    return posts
  }
}
    
func fetchPost(id: Int) async throws -> Post {
  // Grabs a post and returns it or throws
}
```

The code works but it seems like a lot of code for a simple task, is there any way to simplify the code?
The other issue is that I need the order of the posts to be consistent with the order in the ids array that I use to request them, how would I go about that?

Comment: Is there anything in the `Post` data that can be used to sort them after receiving them?

Comment: @Fogmeister no unfortunately not, the order should come from the list of id's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is the correct pattern for fetching multiple Posts *simultaneously* (concurrently). You don't have to do that; you could fetch them *sequentially*, i.e. one at a time. The code for that would be a lot simpler — but would take much longer to run, since each fetch must wait upon completion of the previous one:

```
func fetchPostSequentially(ids: [Int]) async throws -> [Post] {
    var posts = [Post]()
    for id in ids {
        posts.append(try await self.fetchPost(id: id))
    }
    return posts
}
```

That will give you your Posts in the same order as the original `ids` — but, as I say, it will be terribly slow and inefficient.

Assuming that you *do* want to fetch your Posts simultaneously, your code has a major weakness: you have lost the advantage of preserving the linkage between the `id` (which is what you seem to have in advance) and the corresponding Post. As you rightly say, the results come back in no order. There is nothing you can do about that; the fetching is asynchronous and simultaneous, so individual fetches can complete in any order.

But it is not the *order* that is important, but rather the association of the original `id` with its post. It would be better, therefore, rather than worrying about order, to form a dictionary of Post values keyed by `id`:

```
func fetchPosts(ids: [Int]) async throws -> [Int:Post] {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: [Int:Post].self) { taskGroup in
        var posts = [Int:Post]()
        for id in ids {
            taskGroup.addTask { return [id: try await self.fetchPost(id: id)] }
        }
        for try await post in taskGroup {
            posts.merge(post, uniquingKeysWith: {one, two in one})
        }
        return posts
    }
}
```

That way, you can fetch all posts using an initially known list of `id` values, and henceforth you have a perpetually useful dictionary where accessing a Post by its `id` is instant.

As for your initial misgivings that "it seems like a lot of code for a simple task": No, it isn't, that's the pattern — which makes perfect sense as soon as you understand what a task group *is*. So just suck it up and get used to it. It's boilerplate so it's not difficult to do once you have the habit.

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful.

Comment: Simplified the first example.

Comment: This would have been a helpful answer for my question the other day that asked something similar. It also went down the taskGroup route which does seem way more complex than using Combine. 

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought your first snippet of code was an answer but I can see now that it is not. It still seems like a much better option to use Combine for something like this over async await. Until async await has something like JavaScript’s `Promise.all`

Comment: @Fogmeister - That (ordered results) is easily achieved with judicious use of `reduce`. You can easily write an extension to wrap this in a nice, convenient method (e.g., see `throwingAsyncValues` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71163450/1271826)) if you don’t want to encumber the calling point with this logic.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Matt, namely that you should consider returning a dictionary, which is order-independent, but offers O(1) retrieval of results. I might suggest a slightly more concise implementation:

```swift
func fetchPosts(ids: [Int]) async throws -> [Int: Post] {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: (Int, Post).self) { group in
        for id in ids {
            group.addTask { try await (id, self.fetchPost(id: id)) }
        }

        return try await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
    }
}
```

Or if `Post` conformed to `Identifiable`, and then the tuple kruft is no longer necessary:

```swift
func fetchPosts(ids: [Post.ID]) async throws -> [Post.ID: Post] {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Post.self) { group in
        for id in ids {
            group.addTask { try await self.fetchPost(id: id) }
        }

        return try await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.id] = $1 }
    }
}
```

And if you want to return `[Post]`, just build the array from the dictionary:

```swift
func fetchPosts(ids: [Post.ID]) async throws -> [Post] {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Post.self) { group in
        for id in ids {
            group.addTask { try await self.fetchPost(id: id) }
        }

        let dictionary = try await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.id] = $1 }
        return ids.compactMap { dictionary[$0] }
    }
}
```

Your implementation may vary, but hopefully, this illustrates another pattern.

---

By the way, if you do this a lot, you might define a `Sequence` extension that does this for you, e.g.:

```swift
extension Sequence where Element: Sendable {
    @inlinable public func throwingAsyncValues<T>(
        of type: T.Type = T.self,
        body: @escaping @Sendable (Element) async throws -> T
    ) async rethrows -> [T] {
        try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: (Int, T).self) { group in
            for (index, value) in enumerated() {
                group.addTask { try await (index, body(value)) }
            }

            let dictionary = try await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
            return enumerated().compactMap { dictionary[$0.0] }
        }
    }
}
```

Used as follows:

```swift
func fetchPosts(ids: [Post.ID]) async throws -> [Post] {
    try await ids.throwingAsyncValues { id in
        try await self.fetchPost(id: id)
    }
}
```

Obviously, you can easily make a non-`throwing` rendition, too, but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea of extensions to simplify the calling point.

Comment: Cool o rama! I always forget that async sequence does have some sequence-like methods.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from @Rob, however a caveat should be added: a task group executes its tasks on separate threads (and that's the whole point of it) which can have some nasty unintended consequences if you are accessing unprotected static data. Within the SwiftUI context where `@State` (and especially `@StateObject`) properties are protected automatically, you will generally be safe, but in other situations and especially with accessing global static data you may run into crashes or race conditions at best.

Moreover, running lightweight stuff like network requests without any heavy computations concurrently usually makes little sense. Another solution to this problem is to use `Task { ... }` instead, like so:

```
func fetchPosts(ids: [Post.ID]) async throws -> [Post.ID: Post] {
    let tasks = ids.map {
        Task {
            try await self.fetchPost(id: id)
        }
    }
    var result: [Post.ID: Post] = [:]
    // Can't use functional style here since async throwing code can't
    // be used within `.map()` and friends.
    for i in ids.indices {
        result[ids[i]] = try await tasks[i].value
    }
    return result
}
```

The advantage of this is that the tasks will run within the same context as the enclosing code except it will be asynchronous. Note that Swift still can fork the `await` part into a different thread but the code within task's `action` will be guaranteed to be run within the same context.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get much shorter that that. You can take some shortcuts to make the code more concise, and reduce the number of lines, by taking advantage of some functional programming aspects:

```swift
func fetchPosts(ids: [Int]) async throws -> [Post] {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Post.self) { taskGroup in
        ids.forEach { id in
            taskGroup.addTask { try await self.fetchPost(id: id) }
        }
        return try await taskGroup.reduce(into: [Post]()) { $0.append($1) }
    }
}
```

, however on the long run not sure how much this would help.

If you run often enough into needing to fetch data based on an array of ids, you could create a helper function to mitigate this:

```swift
func awaitAll<T, U>(inputs: [T], awaiter: @escaping (T) async throws -> U) async throws -> [U] {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: U.self) { taskGroup in
        for input in inputs {
            taskGroup.addTask { try await awaiter(input) }
        }
        var results = [U]()
        for try await result in taskGroup {
            results.append(result)
        }
        return results
    }
}
```

, which case `fetchPosts` would reduce to something like this:

```swift
func fetchPosts(ids: [Int]) async throws -> [Post] {
    try await awaitAll(inputs: ids, awaiter: self.fetchPost(id:))
}
```

---

If you need `awaitAll` to return the results in the same order as the ids, then you can change its implementation to something like this:

```swift
func awaitAll<T, U>(inputs: [T], awaiter: @escaping (T) async throws -> U) async throws -> [U] {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: (Int, U).self) { taskGroup in
        for (i, input) in inputs.enumerated() {
            taskGroup.addTask { try await (i, awaiter(input)) }
        }
        var results = [(Int, U)]()
        for try await result in taskGroup {
            results.append(result)
        }
        return results.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }.map(\.1)
    }
}
```

No changes are needed for the callers.